# Delete Sql Query with case statement in oracle11.2

Tags: sql, oracle11gr2

My current code is `create table p(px int primary key, createDate date,updateDate date);`

```
insert into p values(1,'23-JUL-15','25-JUL-15');

 insert into p values(2, '23/JUN/2015','25-JUL-15');

 insert into p values(3, '23/May/2015','25/May/15');

 insert into p values(4, '23/April/2015','25/April/2015');

 insert into p values(5, '23/March/2015','25/March/2015');
```

My Previous query is `delete from p where add_months(sysdate,  - 3) > p.updateDate;`
But, now I want to use looked like if else .
If updateDate is null, I want to use with createDate column.So, now I use case statement.My current query is `DELETE FROM p  WHERE add_months(sysdate,  - 3) > case Updatedate when updatedate IS NULL  else updateDate end;` but now I found error.Can I use delete sql query with case statement.

Comment: you can maybe use the `MERGE` statement with a suitable matcher. Otherwise it will become a procedure in PL/SQL containing the logic.

Comment: You can use nvl function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM p  WHERE add_months(sysdate,  - 3) > 
case when updatedate IS NULL then createDate else updateDate end
```

Comment: ⇒　Yes, It is Ok! Thank you very much, wish you all the best. I'm  not familiar with case statement in sql query. Thanks for your suggestion!